# How display numbers from the first column and count the number of occurance?

Tags: python

I need to display data from the first column and count the number of appearance of every number:

file `Path`:

```
[162 164 168 177 189 190 195 254 255  52]
[152 190 195  74 254 164 249  90 151  52]
[ 47 126 254 152  74 195 164 151 189  52]
[116 120 149 164 152 151 195 189  21  52]
[ 34 195  59 199 252  38  82 189  21  52]
[199 164 151  59  82  38  21 189 227  52]
[ 69 170  38  34 177 153  21 189  52 227]
[ 34 107 177 149 118  21  69 189  52 227]
[ 51  88  75  59  38 107 177 189  52 227]
[109  38 149 112 118  51 177  52 189 227]
[ 89  25  75  59 177 170 107  52 189 227]
[244 107  59 170  88  56  89  52 189 227]
[ 30 183 107  59 170  88  56  52 189 227]
```

Code:

```
file="Path"
with open(file) as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    result = []
    for x in lines:
        result.append(x.split(' ')[0])
    print(result)
    f.close()
```

The expected results are: `162  152, 47, 116, 34, 199, 69, 34, ...`

However,  what my code gives me is:
    ['[162', '[152', '[', '[116', '[', '[199', '[', '[', ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you read your input, you need to be a little more careful in processing each line.  First, slice off the brackets with `x[1:-1]` (eliminate the end characters).
*Now* you can split the line, grab the first field, and convert to an integer:

```
with open("Path") as f:
    result = []

    for line in f.readlines():
        field1 = line[1:-1].split()[0]
        result.append(int(field1))
    print(result)
```

Output:

```
[162, 152, 47, 116, 34, 199, 69, 34, 51, 109, 89, 244, 30]
```

You can collapse this to a single statement if you want:

```
result = [int(line[1:-1].split()[0])
          for line in open("Path").readlines()]
```

Answer (score 0):

To just get the first element of each list:

```
file="Path"
with open(file) as f:
    result = [x[0] for x in f.readlines()]
    print(result)
```

To get counts of those values, use Python's `Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter

file="Path"
with open(file) as f:
    result = [x[0] for x in f.readlines()]
    print(Counter(result))
```

Comment: Because they're reading in as strings instead of lists. You can `eval` them before indexing: `result = [eval(x)[0] for x in f.readlines()]`

Comment: It gives me this error     File "<string>", line 1
    [162 164 168 177 189 190 195 254 255  52]
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax